# My String contains special character ' then how should it be fetched.

Tags: sql-server-2005

In my database there is a string which contains special character ' but when i try to fetch it gives an error saying string termaination eg:

```
String temp=a'bc
SELECT * FROM table where name like 'temp%'
```

Comment: How are you trying to query it?  From client code? From T-SQL in a stored procedure?  Using PHP?  Your code hints at c#/vb.net

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling this from client code (e.g. c#), you use a parameterized query:

```
string temp = "a'bc";
string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE @Name + '%'";

using (var cn = new SqlConnection(" connection string here "))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbTypes.NVarChar, 50).Value = temp;

   cn.Open();
   using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {

       //do something with your data reader
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up the single quote, like so: `a''bc`.

The entire query then becomes

```
SELECT * FROM table where name like 'a''bc%'
```

N.B. If the pattern in question is derived from user input, beware [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (also see [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you escape quotes in a quoted string by putting them twice, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table where name like 'a''bc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a parametrised query instead of inline SQL

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(50)
SET @var = ISNULL('%' + your_variable_here + '%', '') 

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TableName] where [SomeColumn] like @var
```